# Decision Tree Based Survival Analysis with time-varying covariates in Python

Tags: python, random-forest, survival-analysis, lifelines, scikit-survival

I'd like to predict the remaining survival time with time-varying covariates using Python. I already used [lifelines' CoxTimeVaryingFitter](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Time%20varying%20survival%20regression.html) and would like to compare it to a decision tree based approach, such as [Random Survival Forest](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/sksurv.ensemble.RandomSurvivalForest.html#sksurv.ensemble.RandomSurvivalForest.fit). From [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.00567) I understand, that the "normal" Random Survival Forest is not able to cope with time-varying covariates, but there are extensions to solve that. I could not find any solutions implemented in Python. Have I missed something? I'd also appreciate advice for other modules that can cope with time-varying covariates.

Comment: Hi there, I have the same question, and was wondering whether you were able to come up with a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not. Please let me know, if you have any solution